# Making a Windows 7 style pop up for a NotifyIcon

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, notifyicon

How do I make a Windows 7 style pop up for a NotifyIcon? I'm talking about the type of pop up you get when you click the Wifi or battery icon in the system tray. Like the screenshot below. 
[image: Battery popup[]

I'm guessing it's part of the Windows 7 API Code Pack but I don't know the official name of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by building a form

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 10000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.MinimizeBox = False
    Me.ControlBox = False
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Me.Size = New Size(200, 200)
    Me.Text = ""
    Dim wide As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width
    Dim high As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height
    Me.Location = New Point(wide - 200, high - 200) ' to put it in lower right corner
    'set border style to fixed dialog
    'set startup position to manual
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Close() ' will make the window only stay open for 10 seconds
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]